# Spring Boot GraphQLQueryResolver won't run, runs on test project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, graphql

So I'm new into GraphQL and i got stuff running by manually setup a schemaparser and datafetchers. But I want to refactor and try out by implementing GraphQLQueryResolver to a class and controll my queries from there.

I get it to work by making a new project, but with the same dependencies and should be same implementation, It doesn't run. When I delete the query-methods which reflects the schema, I'll get the error that I need to add methods based on the Queries in the schema, so **I get the confirmation it reaches the class-file** with the implementation of the GraphQLQueryResolver. But I still get this error when i add the rights methods:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLServletRegistrationBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]


----------


 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLHttpServlet' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLHttpServlet' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'invocationInputFactory' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'invocationInputFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchemaProvider' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLWebAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchemaProvider' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLSchema' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 95 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schemaParser' defined in class path resource [com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 109 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 123 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graphql/execution/batched/Batched
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolver$Companion.isBatched(MethodFieldResolver.kt:24) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolver.scanForMatches(MethodFieldResolver.kt:103) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanResolverInfoForPotentialMatches(SchemaClassScanner.kt:230) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner.handleRootType(SchemaClassScanner.kt:122) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScanner.scanForClasses(SchemaClassScanner.kt:80) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.scan(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:151) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParserBuilder.build(SchemaParserBuilder.kt:157) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.schemaParser(GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java:57) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e8bae4.CGLIB$schemaParser$1(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e8bae4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$760fcbb7.invoke(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at com.oembedler.moon.graphql.boot.GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42e8bae4.schemaParser(<generated>) ~[graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure-5.0.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 124 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: graphql.execution.batched.Batched
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519) ~[na:na]
    ... 142 common frames omitted
```

Dependencies:

```
    implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphql-java-tools:5.2.4'
    implementation 'com.graphql-java:graphiql-spring-boot-starter:5.0.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.3'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.6.3'
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.3'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.3'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
```

My Entity class, same as in test-project:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name= "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name= "username", unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name= "password")
    private String password;
```

Query-class:

```
package com.WineOutBE.resolver;

import com.WineOutBE.Entity.User;
import com.WineOutBE.Repo.UserRepository;
import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public List<User> AllUsers() {

        return userRepository.findAll();}
    }
```

Schema "user.graphqls", lays in resources -> graphql:

```
type Query {
    AllUsers: [User]
}

type User {
    id: Long
    username: String
    firstname: String
    lastname: String
}
```

Application properties for the graphql

```
graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
graphql.servlet.enabled=true

graphiql.enabled=true
graphiql.endpoint=/graphql
graphiql.mapping=graphiql
```

It runs with the same Entity, Repository, Dependencies, application.properties on a new basic project just for testing the GraphQL.
Does anybody see the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a .graphqlconfig?

Comment: it seems like you have missing dependency. try to diagnose dependencies and running spring boot in debug mode. that might help to understand differences between test project and the failing one

Comment: @DanielJacob, Hey Daniel! No I don't have a config in none of the projects. Maybe I should look that up too.

Comment: @Alexander, Hej Alexander! Alright, I'll give it a try. I litteraly copy the implementation dependencies AND now when I checked.. i didn't have the same Spring Boot version plugin in the top.. In my main i had 2.7.0 and in the test 2.6.3. I doesn't compile with 2.7.0 for some reason.. gonna run it on 2.6.3. But curious on why it doesn't run on 2.7.0.

Comment: @Linus you in most cases would want to use bom (dependency management) instead of manually specifying versions, that would help to avoid dependency hell; try it out, probably it'll solve your issue

Comment: @Alexander, thank you for your tip! I'll take that with me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**-- Solved --**

So I ran my default project on Spring Boot 2.7.0 and 2.6.3 on my test project. When I changed to 2.6.3 on default, it ran. So it seems like the latest GrahpQL isn't fully compatible with Spring Boot 2.7.0 yet. Which might be obvious because it was released in the last month.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GraphQL Java Kickstart instead of downgrading the version of Spring Boot.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>13.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```